# Use dates as indicators to a function from two different dataframes

Tags: r, function, loops, date, dataframe

I got two dataframes which looks like the following:

dataframe1

```
  individual   OpenDate  CloseDate MeanReturn
1          1 2010-01-04 2010-01-08        NaN
2          2 2010-01-01 2010-01-08        NaN
3          3 2010-01-03 2010-01-06        NaN
4          4 2010-01-02 2010-01-05        NaN
5          5 2010-01-04 2010-01-06        NaN
```

And
dataframe2

```
        Date Return
1 2010-01-01    532
2 2010-01-02    645
3 2010-01-03    213
4 2010-01-04    567
5 2010-01-05    986
6 2010-01-06    123
7 2010-01-07    567
8 2010-01-08    654
```

What I need to do is to somehow calculate the MeanReturn for each individual, e.g. for individual 5: MeanReturn = (567+986+123)/3

My real data consists of over 10,000 individuals with a time-period over 2 years, so it's not something easily done by hand unfortunately.

I have been stuck on this problem for almost two weeks now and it's driving me insane - any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you want to share data in the `r` tag please include a `dput()` of it. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: so for each row you want mean of the one before and after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the second data frame has its returns sorted by `Date`, we can use `match` to find the range of `Return` to average:

```
df1$MeanReturn=mapply(function(o,c) mean(df2$Return[o:c]), match(df1$OpenDate,df2$Date), match(df1$CloseDate,df2$Date))
```

Here we use `mapply` to apply the `mean` function to the open and close rows in the second data frame `df2` that matches `df1$OpenDate` and `df1$CloseDate`, respectively.

Using the data you provided, `df1` becomes:

```
df1
##  individual   OpenDate  CloseDate MeanReturn
##1          1 2010-01-04 2010-01-08   579.4000
##2          2 2010-01-01 2010-01-08   535.8750
##3          3 2010-01-03 2010-01-06   472.2500
##4          4 2010-01-02 2010-01-05   602.7500
##5          5 2010-01-04 2010-01-06   558.6667
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(individual = 1:5, OpenDate = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", 
"2010-01-04"), class = "factor"), CloseDate = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2010-01-05", "2010-01-06", "2010-01-08"
), class = "factor"), MeanReturn = c(579.4, 535.875, 472.25, 
602.75, 558.666666666667)), .Names = c("individual", "OpenDate", 
"CloseDate", "MeanReturn"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
##  individual   OpenDate  CloseDate MeanReturn
##1          1 2010-01-04 2010-01-08   579.4000
##2          2 2010-01-01 2010-01-08   535.8750
##3          3 2010-01-03 2010-01-06   472.2500
##4          4 2010-01-02 2010-01-05   602.7500
##5          5 2010-01-04 2010-01-06   558.6667

df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("2010-01-01", 
"2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-06", 
"2010-01-07", "2010-01-08"), class = "factor"), Return = c(532L, 
645L, 213L, 567L, 986L, 123L, 567L, 654L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Return"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
##        Date Return
##1 2010-01-01    532
##2 2010-01-02    645
##3 2010-01-03    213
##4 2010-01-04    567
##5 2010-01-05    986
##6 2010-01-06    123
##7 2010-01-07    567
##8 2010-01-08    654
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly with the sample. But when I try to use it on my main data it says:
"Error in o:c : NA/NaN argument"
I'm guessing it's because there exists NaN:s when matching the main data, but not the example. 
Is it possible to solve?

Comment: @Layte: Yes, that will be a problem. `match` only perform exact matches so that the range of `Date` in `df2` must include those in `OpenDate` and `CloseDate` in `df1`. What you should do is to (i) get the range of `OpenDate` and `CloseDate` in `df1`, (ii) merge `df2` with this range in dates so that missing dates have `Return` equal to `NA`, then use the above `mapply` with `mean(df2$Return[o:c], na.rm=TRUE)` to ignore the `NA` values in the mean. I'll edit the answer with these suggestions, but it may be an hour or two before I do.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. After giving the data a thorough look I noticed that I had made an error when lagging dates previously - (I accidentally removed Fridays and kept Saturdays, which no trade happens on) so the matching for the individuals on Friday had no return-date to match with.
Adjusting it solved everything and your code works flawlessly. Thank you so much!